# Adjust the overlapping dates in group by with priority from another columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

As Title Suggest, I am working on a problem to find overlapping dates based on ID and adjust overlapping date based on priority(weight). Following piece of code helped to find overlapping dates.

```
df['overlap'] = (df.groupby('ID')
                   .apply(lambda x: (x['End_date'].shift() - x['Start_date']) > timedelta(0))
                   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
df
```

Now issue I'm facing is, how to introduce priority(weight) and adjust start_date by that.  In the below image, I have highlighted adjusted dates based on weight where A takes precedence over B and B takes over C.

[image]

Should I create a dictionary for string to numeric weight values and then what? I'm stuck here to set up logic.

Dataframe:

```
op_d = {'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],'Start_date':['9/1/2020','10/10/2020','11/18/2020','4/1/2015','5/12/2016','4/1/2015','5/15/2016','8/1/2018'],\
        'End_date':['10/9/2020','11/25/2020','12/31/2020','5/31/2016','12/31/2016','5/29/2016','9/25/2018','10/15/2020'],\
       'Weight':['A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=op_d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already identified the overlap condition, you can then try adding a day to End_Date and shift, then assign them to start date where overlap column is true:

```
arr = np.where(df['overlap'],df['End_date'].add(pd.Timedelta(1,unit='d')).shift(),
     df['Start_date'])
out = df.assign(Output_Start_Date = arr,Output_End_Date=df['End_date'])
```

---

```
print(out)
   ID Start_date   End_date Weight  overlap Output_Start_Date Output_End_Date
0   1 2020-09-01 2020-10-09      A    False        2020-09-01      2020-10-09
1   1 2020-10-10 2020-11-25      B    False        2020-10-10      2020-11-25
2   1 2020-11-18 2020-12-31      C     True        2020-11-26      2020-12-31
3   2 2015-04-01 2016-05-31      A    False        2015-04-01      2016-05-31
4   2 2016-05-12 2016-12-31      B     True        2016-06-01      2016-12-31
5   3 2015-04-01 2016-05-29      A    False        2015-04-01      2016-05-29
6   3 2016-05-15 2018-09-25      B     True        2016-05-30      2018-09-25
7   3 2018-08-01 2020-10-15      C     True        2018-09-26      2020-10-15
```

Comment: Consider a scenario where rows are not sorted by weight or weight has different priority i.e. B > A > C in the above data frame. In this case the above code will not work and have to look up weight or sort by weight order?

Comment: @Prish yes this is considering the weights are sorted, if your priority order changes , you can first convert the weight column to categorical(if you already haven't) by `df['Weight'] = pd.Categorical(df['Weight'],categories=['B','A','C'],ordered=True)` and then sort by `ID` and `Weight`  `df=df.sort_values(['ID','Weight'])` , then use this code

Comment: @Prish or specifically to your comment `pd.Categorical(df['Weight'],categories=['C','A','B'],ordered=True)` gives `[C < A < B]`